# Sencha Touch set data

Tags: sencha-touch

I want set data from controller into formpanel(textfields). But not working.

This is code :

Strore

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CV_FamilyList',
{
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires : ['MyApp.model.CV_FamilyList'],
config :
{
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'MyApp.model.CV_FamilyList',
    storeId : 'CV_FamilyList',
    proxy :
    {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '?b=Family',
        reader :
        {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'data'
        }
    }
}
});
```

Model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.CV_FamilyList',
{
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
config :
{
    fields : [
    {
        name : 'id'
    },
    {
        name : 'member'
    },
    {
        name : 'firstname'
    },
    {
        name : 'lastname'
    }]
},
GetPosition : function() {
    var d = this.data, names = [d.Position];
    return names.join(" ");
}
});
```

LIST

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.CV_FamilyEdit',
{
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype : 'CV_FamilyEdit',
config :
{
    scrollable : true,
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'member',
            label: 'member'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'firstname',
            label: 'firstname'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'lastname',
            label: 'lastname'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Controller

```
onCV_FamilyListItemTap : function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {

    this.getMain().push(
    {
        xtype : 'CV_FamilyEdit',
        title : record.data.firstname+" "+record.data.lastname,
        data : record.data
    });
}
```

............................................................
............................................................

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May be this work.

```
   onCV_FamilyListItemTap : function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
   this.getMain().push(
        {
          xtype : 'CV_FamilyEdit',
          title : record.data.firstname+" "+record.data.lastname,
          data: record.getData() 
       });
  },
```

Comment: @David Shonia can u provide coding of your "list view". I will work on your problem.

Comment: Ext.define('MyApp.view.CV_FamilyList',{extend : 'Ext.dataview.List',xtype : 'CV_FamilyList',config :{height : 500,loadingText : 'მონაცემები იტვირთება ...',store : 'CV_FamilyList',itemTpl : ['<div style="">','<table width="100%" border="0"><tr><td style="width:100%;font-size:17px;">','<div style="color:#660099;">{member}</div>','<div style="font-size:16px; padding-top:3px; color:black;">{firstname} {lastname}</div>','<td style="width:5%; cursor:pointer;">','<img src="./image/full_vacancy.png" border="0" />','</td></tr></table>','</div>']}});

Comment: @David Shonia Its better if u edit your question & add this code there. Anyways i w'll start looking.

Comment: @David Shonia I w'll also need you app.js & store.js because its hard to guess which approach are you using.
Kindly update your question with code.

Answer (score 0):

I done

```
constructor : function(config) {
        this.callParent(config);
        this.setValues(
        {
            member : config.data.member,
            firstname : config.data.firstname,
            lastname : config.data.lastname
        })
    }
```